# My mac terminal can't run python functions

Tags: python, macos, function, terminal

I've tried to run multiple python functions on mac terminal and they all return syntax error, for this program

```
def spam():
   print "R"

spam()
```

it returned the error:

```
./test.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.py: line 1: `def spam():'
```

this is really the simplest function I could find.

Just to be clear terminal is running the rest of the program but it can't handle functions.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math

number = int(raw_input("What's your surd?"))

print type(number)

#Just to let us know what the input is

if type(number) == int:
    print "Number is an integer"
else:
    print "Please enter a number"

value = math.sqrt(number)

#Takes the number and square roots it

new_value =  int(value)

#Turns square root of number into an integer

if type(new_value) == int:
    print "Surd can be simplified"
    print new_value
else:
    print "Surd cannot be simplified"
    print value
```

This program runs fine even if it is a bit buggy at the moment but the following program returns the same error as the previous function.

```
# define a function
def print_factors(x):
   print("The factors of",x,"are:")
   for i in range(1, x + 1):
       if x % i == 0:
           print(i)


num = int(input("What's your number? "))

print_factors(num)
```

Why terminal is returning a syntax error where there isn't one?

Comment: How are you running your python program? Try `python ./test.py`.

Comment: The error message you're getting indicates that the `bash` shell is trying to interpret that file. You will get an identical message if you type `def spam():` into the shell. That implies that the file doesn't contain a proper shebang line (like the `#!/usr/bin/python` you show in your longer excerpt).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here (at least for that first example) is that you're not using a python interpreter.  The terminal is using a bash interpreter for your python code and getting very confused.  Use a command like this to execute your code `python spam.py` . Or first enter the python command interpreter by running `python`, then entering your code in the command line interpreter.

What might be even easier while getting started is to get an IDE like PyCharm (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and running through a couple of their tutorials to get the feel of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your shell doesn't know you are running a Python script. You need to make it clear that you should be using the Python interpreter. You can either do this by:

1) Call `python test.py` at your terminal.

2) Add `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of your Python script (you may need to alter the path to the Python executable on your system). Make the script executable, and call `./test.py` at your terminal.

The benefits of 2) are that you know what version of Python you will be running your script with (Python 2.x in your case?).

Method 1) will use whatever Python version is encountered first in your PATH, which may be Python 3 or Python 2, depending on whether you have installed Python 3 at some point. The code you have written will work with Python 2.7, but not Python 3.x. Of course you can always explicitly call `python2.7 ./test.py`.